# Find checksum of every dependency in golang

Tags: go, go-modules, go-packages

I want to be able to get the checksum of every package used by a go program, including packages used within modules.

`runtime/debug` in the standard library has `ReadBuildInfo()`, which is great, but it only gives data for modules, not for packages.

Example:

```
package pkgA

var Foo = 1
```

```
package pkgB

import "pkgA"

var Bar = pkgA.Foo
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"

    "example/pkgB"
)

func main() {
    _ = pkgB.Bar

    b, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo()
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("not ok!")
        return
    }

    for _, module := range b.Deps {
        fmt.Println(module.Path, module.Sum)
    }
}
```

The output is like

```
pkgB v0.0.0-20210225235400-92e28d816f64
```

There is no info on A. I believe this is because `pkgB` and `pkgA` both belong to the same module.

**Question**: Is there any way to access the checksum for `pkgA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go checksum database stores checksums for modules, not packages.
The debug information embedded in a binary does not include the mapping from packages to modules, but if you have access to the module's source you can use [`go list`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-List_packages_or_modules) to report the mapping from packages to modules:

```
go list -f '{{if .Module}}{{.ImportPath}}: {{.Module}}{{end}}' all
```

You can use that mapping, in conjunction with the module-level checksums, to verify that each package has the correct source code. (Note that `go mod verify` already implements that verification.)

Comment: I was hoping to get the package checksum from the binary, so it sounds like I can't quite do what I need. Thank you though! It is our source code, so I will do something with `go list` instead.